# <picture> element not switching based on media in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to revamp a site to make it responsive.
I've got a horizontal header image to use for the desktop site (>700px) and a vertical image with a css background on smaller sites (<700px).

I've got it all working but in Firefox, the base desktop image doesn't replace. I've futzed with all kinds of ways of doing it, but can't get Firefox to play along - Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari, and even Android browsers are playing along.

Here's a very simple version of the page: http://thefloatcenter.com/test.html
Here's the code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8b46L9av/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
<style>
#container,#header {
    width: 800px;
}
header#header #logo {
    border: 0;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #container, header#header {
    /*max-width: 700px;*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    header#header {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #484A5D, #000104);
        background: linear-gradient(#484A5D, #1B1D25, #000104);
        text-align: center;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <picture id="logo" title="FLOAT - Floatation Center and Art Gallery, an Urban Art Spa" alt="FLOAT - Floatation Center and Art Gallery, an Urban Art Spa." >
            <source srcset=".images/banner2.jpg" media="(min-width: 700px)" >
            <source srcset=".images/banner_vert_trans_sml.png">
             <img src=".images/banner2.jpg"  >
        </picture>
    </a>
    </header> 
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="rtcontent">
            <a name="top"> </a>
            <h1><a id="services"></a>A title here</h1>
        </div><!-- end rtcontent -->
        <nav id="sidenav">
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="keywords">
        <p>cool stuff at the bottom</p>
    </div><!-- end keywords -->
    </div>  <!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It works on pageload, but does not switch on resize.

Comment: I had it working a while ago, in combination with picturefill. To be honest: I don't know if it worked native or because of picturefill. I can only tell you how it is at the moment. Picturefill isn't called (because picture is supported) but FF native behaviour is broken. I tried removing the part, where PF asks for support (So it runs wether or not the browser already supports picture), but that doesn't work, too. I think FF "overwrites" PF somehow.

Comment: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/gh-pages/plugins/static-gecko-picture/ls.static-gecko-picture.js